# Paypal IPN for subscription agreement

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions, webhooks

I have integrated Paypal subscription plan, and subscribing the plan in rails app. Now I am looking to integrate webhooks for paypal payments. I am really struggling hard to make paypal work. This is my third question related with Paypal subscription, however I have solved earlier questions by myself. But  could do better if there was good documentation in paypal.

I found there are IPN for subscription/recurring payment but I can not find the field with which I can relate the IPN with existing subscription. I am storing subscription_id i.e. agreement_id but in IPN i am not able to find agreement_id.

Please suggest what to do.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the agreement_id value in the custom field. You should get the custom field back during each IPN.